# C use macro struct in function prototypes

Tags: c, struct, macros

I am simulating templates in C using macros. I would like to achieve something like this:

```c
// Struct.h
#define define_struct(type) \
  typedef struct MyStruct { \
    type value;             \
  }

struct MyStruct;
typedef struct MyStruct MyStruct;

MyStruct *createMyStruct();
```

```c
// Struct.c
#include "Struct.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

MyStruct *createMyStruct() {
  MyStruct *str = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
  return str;
}
```

Then use it:

```c
#include "Struct.h"

define_struct(int);

int main() {
  MyStruct *str = createMyStruct();
}
```

But this doesn't work because `struct MyStruct;` is an incomplete type and `malloc(MyStruct)` doesn't make sense to the compiler. Is it possible to do this without errors?

P.S. I understand, *why* this doesn't work, I am absolutely sure I will never need to define 2 instances of this struct and I cannot use C++, only plain C.

Comment: Please do not use macros for this. It makes the code difficult to read and debug. I feel for the person that will come back to this code in a years time trying to understand it. Just do it long hand. Makes life a lot easier in the long run.

Comment: You will have to compile `Struct.c` with the correct invocation of `defined_struct` in scope.  Further, you will only be able to have one type in any given program.  If you want more than one of these types in a program, you will have to create functions with different names for different types, and you've not attempted to do that. That typically involves token pasting using the `##` operator in macros, and you'll need many more macros than just the one you have at the moment. It won't make your code readable; it won't make your code easy to understand; it will make it hard to maintain. Don't!

Comment: Put succinctly, if you want C++, use C++.

Comment: Macro in c are just used by preprocessor. For example, in struct.c you do not use defined_struct(xxx) before using MyStruct, so the compiler can not compile undefined structure.

Comment: To understand **_why_** you got the diagnostic, put yourself in the role of the compiler while compiling "Struct.c": How many bytes should be passed to `malloc()` without knowing how big `MyStruct` is?

Comment: You can do object-oriented programming in C, but then do it correctly. If you want something like `new`, write a function `new()` for each type you need.

Comment: the kewword `typedef` in the macro makes no sense. But the code you posted would work, if `#include "MyStruct"` is changed to `#include "Struct.h"` and you define the struct in the header.   If you don't want to define it in the header you will need to add a size argument to the allocation function (this could be a macro).  And if you want to use this "template" more than once you're going to have to paste something into the struct name so different instances don't clash.

Answer (score 0):

There is a classic book titled **C Interfaces and Implementations: Techniques for Creating Reusable Software**, in which there is an in-depth discussion of the very same thing. It is in the first chapter, if I remember.

There should be 2 solutions:

1. Define all member functions like `createMyStruct` as a macro with `(type)` too.
2. Use an `impl` pointer, like:

```c
struct MyStruct {
    void *impl;

    /* stuff that store actual type of imple and something else */
    some_type_to_store_type actual_type;
};

MyStruct *createMyStruct(some_type_to_store_type actual_type) {
  MyStruct *str = malloc(sizeof(Mystruct));
       // wow! sizeof Mystruct is fixed now
  str->impl = make_impl(actual_type);
  return str;
}
```

Also, there are some libraries using this coding style, but I can't recall the names. Try search `C OOP` in google and there should be some materials, e.g. this one looks good: https://www.state-machine.com/doc/AN_OOP_in_C.pdf.